# Inventor DA model fails to update with parameters

Tags: autodesk-inventor

```
Here's the report:

[11/22/2020 19:32:37] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\InventorCoreConsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[UpdateParameters].path)\" /ilod \"$(args[InventorDoc].path)\" /paramFile \"$(args[InventorParams].path)\" /p",
  "$(engine.path)\\InventorCoreConsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[CreateSVF].path)\" /ilod \"$(args[InventorDoc].path)\"",
  "$(engine.path)\\InventorCoreConsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[CreateBOM].path)\" /i \"$(args[InventorDoc].path)\""
]
"Settings":{
  "dasreportfaileduploadoptional": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57"
"ActivityId":"rEjXU4U1NdTFXijVrv0Gk4gHjZ4GIAu5.UpdateProject+green"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Inventor!16"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"rEjXU4U1NdTFXijVrv0Gk4gHjZ4GIAu5.UpdateParameters!244",
"App.Id":"rEjXU4U1NdTFXijVrv0Gk4gHjZ4GIAu5.CreateSVF!258",
"App.Id":"rEjXU4U1NdTFXijVrv0Gk4gHjZ4GIAu5.CreateBOM!244"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "InventorDoc": {
    "localName": "unzippedIam",
    "pathInZip": "KGYP19015A2.iam",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:ngtwUHWkB+53dSafxxeKklHjaAY="
  },
  "InventorParams": {
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:nSkfbv16UKUVkda1fLPHnLrIQ2c="
  },
  "OutputModelIAMFile": {
    "zip": true,
    "optional": true,
    "localName": "unzippedIam",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:IJMn49m5OR7Rp0d/qIbRoeMVgfA=",
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "OutputModelIPTFile": {
    "optional": true,
    "localName": "part.ipt",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:9Hgb+t/yh/mlcaYvtNNdlKoLzOc=",
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "UpdateParametersOutput": {
    "localName": "documentParams.json",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:oX2a3yEb6BuYNOH2aw+Oz8muQM0=",
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "CreateSVFOutput": {
    "zip": true,
    "localName": "SvfOutput",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:zfJkvzf3Rh9d6x4gSQ01cBfH+0I=",
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "CreateBOMOutput": {
    "localName": "bom.json",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:RfRpLNgQ7PEIV6mlNf1Ny8jvxUQ=",
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"rEjXU4U1NdTFXijVrv0Gk4gHjZ4GIAu5\"},\"scope\":\"code:all\",\"expires_in\":3406,\"client_id\":\"rEjXU4U1NdTFXijVrv0Gk4gHjZ4GIAu5\"}"
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 900,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 500
}
[11/22/2020 19:32:37] Folder "T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\unzippedIam" has been created.
[11/22/2020 19:32:37] Folder "T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\SvfOutput" has been created.
[11/22/2020 19:32:37] Starting work item 8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57
[11/22/2020 19:32:37] Start download phase.
[11/22/2020 19:32:37] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/437b5b9f-5a36-47d3-88d4-d90e267d9dd5?region=US'
[11/22/2020 19:32:37] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/f0738489-7894-4487-9773-9686aecc6390?region=US'
[11/22/2020 19:32:38] '675' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\0c74b265385e4634ac3dcc233e952dca.input-params.json.
[11/22/2020 19:32:38] End downloading file 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/f0738489-7894-4487-9773-9686aecc6390?region=US'.
[11/22/2020 19:32:41] '87952255' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\zip_467.zip.
[11/22/2020 19:32:41] End downloading file 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/437b5b9f-5a36-47d3-88d4-d90e267d9dd5?region=US'.
[11/22/2020 19:32:41] Error: Failed to parse the ETransmit Archive: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at CoreEngineRunner.DownloadItem.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<TryParseProductWorkFlowArchive>g__TestArchive|0(Encoding& encoding, String& resolvedName, String& codePage)
   at CoreEngineRunner.DownloadItem.TryParseProductWorkFlowArchive(Stream stream, String hintMatchName, String& resolvedName, String& codePage)
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\zip_467.zip has been unpacked to folder T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\unzippedIam.
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] End download phase successfully.
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] Command line: [ /al "T:\Aces\Applications\f4d2283bfec7651de654f6e5a63411d2.rEjXU4U1NdTFXijVrv0Gk4gHjZ4GIAu5.UpdateParameters[244].package" /ilod "T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\unzippedIam\KGYP19015A2.iam" /paramFile "T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\0c74b265385e4634ac3dcc233e952dca.input-params.json" /p]
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] Command line: [ /al "T:\Aces\Applications\f249bab2b1092803f8b375e5bec77255.rEjXU4U1NdTFXijVrv0Gk4gHjZ4GIAu5.CreateSVF[258].package" /ilod "T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\unzippedIam\KGYP19015A2.iam"]
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] Command line: [ /al "T:\Aces\Applications\0d9312d28a9bc584cc602b0d6f071f2f.rEjXU4U1NdTFXijVrv0Gk4gHjZ4GIAu5.CreateBOM[244].package" /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\unzippedIam\KGYP19015A2.iam"]
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] Start script phase.
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] ### Command line arguments: /isolate HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57 "T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\userdata" /exe "T:\Aces\AcesRoot\25.00\coreEngine\Exe\InventorCoreConsole.exe"  /al "T:\Aces\Applications\f4d2283bfec7651de654f6e5a63411d2.rEjXU4U1NdTFXijVrv0Gk4gHjZ4GIAu5.UpdateParameters[244].package" /ilod "T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\unzippedIam\KGYP19015A2.iam" /paramFile "T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\0c74b265385e4634ac3dcc233e952dca.input-params.json" /p.
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] Start Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : InventorCoreConsole.exe: 25.0.18300.0
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Starting Inventor Server.
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Started Inventor Server 2021.1 (Build 251245000, 245) (25, 10, 24500, 0000)
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Loading plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[11/22/2020 19:32:44]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: iLogic Plugin
[11/22/2020 19:32:44]     iLogic Plugin: initializing...
[11/22/2020 19:32:44] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Creating default project file with name: FDADefault at T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57
[11/22/2020 19:32:45] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating default project T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\FDADefault.ipj
[11/22/2020 19:32:45] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Getting Inventor plug-in.
[11/22/2020 19:32:45] InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Plug-in: UpdateParametersPlugin
[11/22/2020 19:32:45]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Activating plug-in: UpdateParametersPlugin
[11/22/2020 19:32:45]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : : UpdateParametersPlugin (1.0.0.10): initializing... 
[11/22/2020 19:32:45]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Executing 'RunWithArguments' method on Automation object.
[11/22/2020 19:32:45]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Opening /ilod document name: T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\unzippedIam\KGYP19015A2.iam
[11/22/2020 19:32:45]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : LastActiveDesignViewRepresentation: Default
[11/22/2020 19:32:45]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : LastActiveLevelOfDetailRepresentation: Master
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Full document name: T:\Aces\Jobs\8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57\unzippedIam\KGYP19015A2.iam
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : ExecWithArguments called with KGYP19015A2.iam with 6 arguments
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Read parameters
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : {"WallConstruction":{"value":"\u0022Fire Rated Construction\u0022","unit":"Text","values":["\u0022Standard Construction\u0022","\u0022Insulated 50mm\u0022","\u0022Insulated 75mm\u0022","\u0022Insulated 100mm\u0022","\u0022Acoustic 2mm\u0022","\u0022Fire Rated Construction\u0022","\u0022SR2 Construction\u0022","\u0022SR3 Construction\u0022","\u0022SR4 Construction\u0022"],"readonly":false,"label":"WallConstruction"},"Width":{"value":"3500","unit":"Text","values":[],"readonly":false,"label":"Width"},"Length":{"value":"3000","unit":"Text","values":[],"readonly":false,"label":"Length"},"Height":{"value":"3000","unit":"Text","values":[],"readonly":false,"label":"Height"}}
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Applying '"Fire Rated Construction"' to 'WallConstruction'
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on update for "Fire Rated Construction" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Applying '3500' to 'Width'
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on update for "3500" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Applying '3000' to 'Length'
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on update for "3000" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Applying '3000' to 'Height'
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on update for "3000" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for 1.0 mm and unit type mm / 11269
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for 1.0 mm and unit type mm / 11269
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for 1.0 mm and unit type mm / 11269
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for SelectPanel: Could not convert argument 1 for call to GetPreciseStringFromValue.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for HardwareOperation: Could not convert argument 1 for call to GetPreciseStringFromValue.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for SelectHardware2: Could not convert argument 1 for call to GetPreciseStringFromValue.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for SelectRef: Could not convert argument 1 for call to GetPreciseStringFromValue.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for Distance: Could not convert argument 1 for call to GetPreciseStringFromValue.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for SelectType: Could not convert argument 1 for call to GetPreciseStringFromValue.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for SelectHardware: Could not convert argument 1 for call to GetPreciseStringFromValue.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for SelectHardware3: Could not convert argument 1 for call to GetPreciseStringFromValue.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for SelectHardware4: Could not convert argument 1 for call to GetPreciseStringFromValue.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "Fire Rated Construction" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for WallConstruction: Could not convert argument 1 for call to GetPreciseStringFromValue.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "3500" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for Width: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "3000" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for Height: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Checking expression validity on extraction for "3000" and unit type Text / 11346
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : Can't get nominalValue for Length: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Updating
[11/22/2020 19:32:46]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Saving
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Found 1 iLogic forms
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  - Form 1
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Using 'Form 1' form as a parameter filter
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Closing
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Performing iLogic diagnostics...
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : iLogic error 
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]  Context: RuleRunning 
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]  Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800401F3): Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CLSIDFromProgID(String progId, Guid& clsid)
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(String progID)
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at CodeoDA.KGYP19015A2Rule..ctor()
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at SalesConfigurator.Class1..ctor()
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at ThisRule.Booster()
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Exec.AppDomExec.ExecRuleInAssembly(Assembly assem)
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at iLogic.RuleEvalContainer.ExecRuleEval(String execRule)
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : iLogic error 
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]  Context: RuleRunning 
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]  Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800401F3): Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CLSIDFromProgID(String progId, Guid& clsid)
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(String progID)
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at CodeoDA.KGYP19015A2Rule..ctor()
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at SalesConfigurator.Class1..ctor()
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at ThisRule.Booster()
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Exec.AppDomExec.ExecRuleInAssembly(Assembly assem)
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at iLogic.RuleEvalContainer.ExecRuleEval(String execRule)
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : End of iLogic diagnostics...
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Deactivating plug-in: UpdateParametersPlugin
[11/22/2020 19:32:47]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : : UpdateParametersPlugin: deactivating... 
[11/22/2020 19:32:47] Processing failed
[11/22/2020 19:32:48] End Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[11/22/2020 19:32:48] Error: Application InventorCoreConsole.exe exits with code -1 which indicates an error.
[11/22/2020 19:32:48] End script phase.
[11/22/2020 19:32:48] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[11/22/2020 19:32:48] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[11/22/2020 19:32:48] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/rEjXU4U1NdTFXijVrv0Gk4gHjZ4GIAu5/8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57/report.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGVJZKM3J6Q7ZEO4&Expires=1606078058&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEDMaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQD7G6ktrZVLWT%2BfknqGUDij7QOIGjW2f3glPnQQd6hcmwIgCZ%2BCOl5XRZe%2FqbGdPcc0jwfdaYrOMU4dwlyYAs43bPQq3gEIrP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARACGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDLi1gMNIs1rnR%2FoAVCqyAeISr3d35nEWlPTEcpvRU%2B8X6TqqvKkPYZI3e1XbuIAElo5dvzA%2Bmag4tKvhi7ltLEFoZ2ppO86ohxb3vKOUoaBypd1dzDAxelvLhrQfHDn%2B6NyYwdhlwuHXsOq8LN693ANnDkqFrPStHws3bSpGvIosoOlGszDZgJrFDt65NOREmrE%2FYuy%2F1js9fghaUfwTdOSVa%2BsHk3LEpPscKiUyud3%2B5GkUD5PdiuBOAyhiJQYBxjow1%2Bbq%2FQU64AERb6Sn1QEJiA2%2B3LQk3a83yCYOvgg6rnRMA4IW%2FB6LqBz858vpbSgXlBIq6kmwayfJhOdqMqNBE4FYMwo0ufvEU6WCoRkQnzeUjtbjLAROaAHKWhcxnh5dk1cHv6bAucPo8YfF8JbUAZ3BTDQFRYjacULbIcVewbGJM1ZtCYUZtAFcNrRKdEjK13%2FFP5OmSSH7YZ4YY3UxCTz1c7pt4WTjZ8yCVMzN%2FmMp0ydx%2FvObH4RltaUf%2BT0CHWcFTAZsNMEqzEgugDFtl4%2BPUBDJ1pb66Xb2CLuozNdWGBXJyYdKbw%3D%3D&Signature=YNJqk0GGj0Us3YuH0WwCG0GdrNQ%3D",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2020-11-22T19:32:37.7876783Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2020-11-22T19:32:37.9975809Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2020-11-22T19:32:44.1357867Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2020-11-22T19:32:48.3255927Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 87952930
  },
  "id": "8a15fb482c6145e7a7d18b6abc028a57"
}
```

> We are trying to understand what the problem might be here. It seems like we have problems on the InventorCore about parameter types. Can you help us on this? We are trying to understand the different methods we can use with our automation models.

ignore here I am adding this area because stack overflow is not allowing me to post
ignore here I am adding this area because stack overflow is not allowing me to post
ignore here I am adding this area because stack overflow is not allowing me to post

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please refrain from adding superfluous text to bypass the filters.  It would be better if you'd just explain your problem in a more concise manner.  As is, you need to clarify your problem as "we have problems on the InventorCore" is not very specific.  What problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to check usage of method `GetPreciseStringFromValue`. Because the first argument must be `double`, not empty string.
2. Try to check usage of Form1. Because Inventor.Core doesn't have UI.
3. How do you access to Inventor.Application object? Use `ThisApplication` only. This part of log looks strange.

> [11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CLSIDFromProgID(String progId, Guid& clsid)

> [11/22/2020 19:32:47]    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(String progID)

Comment: We have changed the code accordingly, it is working now. We have other problems though especially, where we are generating parts through DA app. I'll open another thread for it.